# How to Set Up Kodi to Enable Touch Gestures to Control Playback?

Tags: kodi

I am using the current latest `Kodi` version, which is [official website](https://kodi.tv/)

But I don't know how to enable touch gestures to control playback, and I didn't find the relevant user manual on the official website.

I only found [this](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/Nexus/system/keymaps/touchscreen.xml), but it doesn't seem to help me.

The device I'm using is an Android tablet, not a TV. What I want is simple, like other players:

1. Double tap to control pause/play
2. Drag left/right to control playback progress.
3. Double tap left/right to go forward/backward for 10 seconds.
4. etc.

How should I set it up?

Comment: The touch should be working right off the box. Did you download it from play store?

Comment: @44yu5h I download it from `apkpure`